# Weird behaviour when extracting a known interface from a polymorphic container

Tags: c++, interface, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

Could anyone help me understand this behaviour?
To be short:

- I have stored polymorphic objects in a common container.
- Some of them implement a specific interface. I can tell which ones.
- But I can't use this interface.

Here is what I have boilt it down to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


// A base class
struct Base {
    // A polymorphic method
    virtual void describe() const {
        std::cout << "Base" << std::endl;
    };
    virtual ~Base(){
        std::cout << " Base destroyed" << std::endl;
    };
};

// A specific interface
struct Interface {
    virtual ~Interface(){
        std::cout << " Interface Destroyed" << std::endl;
    };
    virtual void specific() = 0;
};

// A derived class..
struct Derived : public Base, public Interface {
    virtual void describe() const {
        std::cout << "Derived" << std::endl;
    };
    virtual void specific() {
        std::cout << "Derived uses Interface" << std::endl;
    };
    virtual ~Derived() {
        std::cout << " Derived destroyed" << std::endl;
    };
};

int main() {

    // Test polymorphism:
    Base* b( new Base() );
    Derived* d( new Derived() );
    b->describe(); // "Base"
    d->describe(); // "Derived"
    // Ok.

    // Test interface:
    d->specific(); // "Derived uses Interface"
    Interface* i(d);
    i->specific(); // "Derived uses Interface"
    // Ok.

    // Here is the situation: I have a container filled with polymorphic `Base`s
    std::vector<Base*> v {b, d};
    // I know that this one implements the `Interface`
    Interface* j((Interface*) v[1]);
    j->specific(); // " Derived destroyed"
                   // " Interface destroyed"
                   // " Base destroyed"
    // Why?! What did that object do to deserve this?

    return EXIT_SUCCESS; // almost -_-
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing there?

*Interesting fact*: If I swap the definitions of `Base::~Base` and `Base::describe`, then the object describes itself instead of being destroyed. How come the order matters in method declarations?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is a good reason to avoid C-style casts. When you do:

```
Interface* j((Interface*) v[1]);
```

That is a `reinterpret_cast`. A C-style cast will try to do, in order: `const_cast`, `static_cast`, `static_cast` then `const_cast`, `reinterpret_cast`, `reinterpret_cast` then `const_cast`. All of these casts, in this case, are wrong! `reinterpret_cast` in particular will just be undefined behavior and it honestly doesn't even matter why you see the specific behavior you see<sup>†</sup>. Undefined behavior is undefined.

What you want to do instead is:

```
Interface* j = dynamic_cast<Interface*>(v[1]);
```

That is the correct cast through the runtime dynamic hierarchy, and will give you the *correct* `Interface*` corresponding to `v[1]` (or `nullptr`, if `v[1]` did not have this runtime type). Once we fix that, then `j->specific()` prints `Derived uses Interface`, as you would expect.

---

<sup>†</sup>Likely, the issue has to do with the vtable alignment. When you do the reinterpret cast, since `Base` does not have a `specific`, it's possible that the offset of that particular function lines up with `~Base()`, so the effect is that you're directly calling the destructor - which is why you see what you see.

Comment: Out of interest, `Interface* j = static_cast<Derived*>(v[1]);` also seems to work, is it safe?

Comment: @ChrisDrew As long as you *know* that `*v[1]` is actually an instance of `Derived` (or a class derived from that), it's safe.

Comment: @ChrisDrew Yes, that's fine because you know it's a `Derived*`, so the `static_cast` is OK. And then pointer-to-derived (`Derived*`) to pointer-to-base (`Interface*`) is a standard conversion, that one is always OK. `dynamic_cast` is safer (but slower) because if `v[1]` were not an `Derived*`, you'd get a well-defined result (a null pointer) instead of a valid-looking pointer that yields undefined behavior if you use it.

Comment: @ChrisDrew Are you asking this because `dynamic_cast` has some overhead against `static_cast`? (I mean: does it?) (NB: in my case I am not supposed to know that `d` is `Derived`, but only that it implements `Interface`)

Comment: @lago-lito Yes, as I understand it, `dynamic_cast` does have significant overhead, I'm told that at least one common implementation is based in part on string comparisons of class names.

Comment: @ChrisDrew Ay! Good to know. Anyway, I am not trying to squeeze out every once of performance out of that program yet. And this looks like the best to do here :)

Comment: As `static_cast<Interface*>` worked, why couldn't `(Interface*)` succeed as well?  The 2nd option that the C-style cast used in your list was `static_cast`, and `reinterpret_cast` was way down the chain.

Comment: @Yakk It was `static_cast<Derived*>` that worked (and assigning *that* to an `Interface*`), `static_cast<Interface*>` would fail to compile.